# ¿Por qué no se insertan elementos en arreglo de mi propia clase?

Tags: java

Estoy implementando una clase que quiero que se comporte como un saco de nombres en que pueda introducir solo los nombre que no estén previamente en el saco. Me está dando un fallo pues no me introduce los nombres en el `saco(Array)`. Llamando a mi propio método `toString()` me muestra todas las posiciones del arreglo a `NULL` como se ve aquí:

[image: Elemento de el array a Null]

Mi estrategia es la siguiente a ver si me podéis ayudar a explicarme por qué no está funcionando correctamente.

```
public void meter(String nombreIntroducir) {

    int i;
    if (contador==nombres.length) {
        agrandarArray();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < contador; i++) {

        if (!nombres[i].equalsIgnoreCase(nombreIntroducir)) {

                nombres[contador]=nombreIntroducir;
                contador++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Este es el contenido del método `agrandarArray()`

```
private void agrandarArray() {
    String[] nuevaLista;
    int i;

    nuevaLista = new String[nombres.length + AUMENTO];

    for (i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++)
        nuevaLista[i] = nombres[i];

    nombres = nuevaLista;
}
```

Método `toString()`

```
public String toString(){

    String aux="";

    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {

        aux+=nombres[i]+",";
    }

    return aux;
}
```

Comment: Hola Ricki bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Primeramente asegura que tu arreglo nombres en realidad contiene valores, ya que veo se estan agregando valores null.

Comment: Por favor muestra el contenido del método `agrandarArray`. Es muy posible que allí esté el problema.

Comment: @Elenasys lo estoy probando con un metodo Main() y le estoy pasando objetos de tipo String pero al parecer la insercion de los elementos no esta correcta,es por ello que me esta mostrando valores Nulos,si no estoy confundido.

Comment: Al parecer eso debería funcionar. ¿Podrías agregar la implementación del método `toString` de tu clase y un ejemplo de cómo estás utilizando tu clase? Quizás allí haya otro problema.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza toString() añadido,gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Que tal! De qué manera le das valor a la variable contador?

Comment: @RosendoRopher esta inicializada dentro de el constructor de el objeto con valor inicial de 0

Comment: Suponiendo que para la primera llamada del método nombres.length = 0 entonces agrandas tu array (y lo pueblas de algo que no existe), para la primera iteración i = 0 y contador = 0, preguntas 0 < 0, la respuesta es no, entonces tu for no hace nada, pero cargas tu array con basura por llamarlo de alguna manera, una prueba de escritorio ayuda bastante, o si prefieres un debug. Saludos!

Comment: Que tal si en lugar de `for (i = 0; i < contador; i++) {` colocas `for (i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {`, te sugiero que debugges tu código, descubrir la falla y solventarla por tu propia investigación. Es bueno entender porqué no funcionan las cosas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ya encontré el problema. Cuando inicializas tu objeto, la variable `contador` tendrá un valor de `0`, y tu `for` en el método `meter` tiene esta condición:

```
for (i = 0; i < contador; i++)
```

Como `contador` vale `0` e `i` vale `0`, la condición `i < contador` devuelve `false` y por ende no se registra ningún dato.

La mejor solución es realizar una validación inicial de esta manera:

```
if (contador == 0) {
    nombres[contador++] = nombreIntroducir;
}
```

Y luego que esto no sucede acudir al `for` de la siguiente manera:

```
if (contador == 0) {
    nombres[contador++] = nombreIntroducir;
} else {
    for (i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
        if (!nombres[i].equalsIgnoreCase(nombreIntroducir)) {
                nombres[contador++] = nombreIntroducir;
                //una vez insertado el elemento, se debe romper el ciclo for
                //para evitar que el mismo elemento se esté duplicando durante la inserción
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

El código de arriba tiene un gran error: que usualmente compara con el primer texto encontrado. Lo que se requiere es verificar que el nombre no exista, y si ese es el caso, entonces agregarlo. La manera de hacerlo es utilizando un método de búsqueda. Este código sería de esta manera:

```
public boolean verificaExistencia(String nombre) {
    boolean resultado = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < contador; i++) {
        if (resultado = nombres[i].equalsIgnoreCase(nombre)) break;
    }
    return resultado;
}

public void meter(String nombreIntroducir) {
    if (contador==nombres.length) {
        agrandarArray();
    }
    if (!verificaExistencia(nombreIntroducir)) {
        nombres[contador++] = nombreIntroducir;
    }
}
```

Comment: Entiendo tu logica perfectamente y tiene todo el sentido de el mundo pero al probar tu codigo me a dado una excepcion IndexOutOfBoundsException: 10

Comment: ¿Puedes colocar el stacktrace en tu comentario? Para revisarlo y ver dónde sucede el problema.

Comment: '`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
 at Ejercicio1.SacoManoInocente.meter(SacoManoInocente.java:29)
 at Ejercicio1.MeH.main(MeH.java:14)`

Comment: Solo por casualidad, ¿no será que removiste la parte que dice `if (contador==nombres.length)`?

Comment: Si te refieres a agrandar el array,no sigue ahi la instrucion con la llamada dentro de el if y por fuera el codigo que me proporcionastes

Comment: Encontré el problema. Respuesta arreglada. Solo debes agregar la sentencia `break` luego de agregar el elemento en el arreglo.

Comment: Muchas gracias,todo solucionado disculpa por los quebraderos de cabeza y la incorrecta formulacion de la pregunta,se mejorara para la proxima.

Comment: No te preocupes. Fue una buena respuesta y buena atención para ser nuevo en el sitio. Bienvenido y que continúes tu participación :). A propósito, si esta respuesta te sirvió, no te olvides de [aceptarla](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/428/227)